# Handling different classes of the same name in a single CS file

Tags: c#, wcf, data-structures, datacontract, data-layers

I'm using two WCF services that declare a class *Donkey* each. Those *Donkey* classes, although identical in structure, aren't the same type, due to namespace issues.

This far I'm using *using* (as described f.i. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345037/how-to-handle-same-class-name-in-different-namespaces)), but I feel that I'd like to get it under some more strict control.

Any suggestions on how (and where) to place a data contract converter that maps the both *Donkey* classes to each other? I know that it's a bit goofy question. It's got to do with the fact that I'm not sure if that's even possible. Feel free to correct my formulation.

All suggestions are welcome. I'm considering writing my own data definition layer and create **my own, better** *Donkey* objects (with booze and hookers, if one dares to use a reference to Futurama's Bender).

Comment: Can you not use different namespaces for two sets of generated code?

Comment: @MichaelGunter If I see the insanely dreadfully chosen namespace names (which are on form *Something.SomethingElse.RandomNumber1234.SomethingHereToo.Donkey*) for more than 5 minutes again, I'm going to kill myself, scratch out my eyes, kill myself again, kick a small dog in pure spite for all things alive and then kill myself a third time. But generally speaking - yes, I can.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you have two identical structures of different types that you want to use interchangeably. In this case, all you need is to define implicit casts. So, in one definition of Donkey, define a cast to and from the other Donkey.

If you do not have control over the two Donkeys or you would prefer to keep the classes decoupled, then adding a third Donkey class would make more sense. In this class, you would define the casts from the other Donkeys.

Depending on the details of your situation, you should try to use just one of the Donkeys as much as you can throughout your project, and only use the other when necessary.

Comment: Control over the original *Donkeys* is out of the question (vacation times/privileges restrictions). Using only one or the other *Donkey* isn't an option because, in fact, I got me a whole farm - I'm in up to five *Donkeys* at the moment and they're going to get more numerous soon. So, the auxiliary transformer donkey-to-donkey seems to be a good option (put in a *NS1.Donkey* - pull out a different *NS2.Donkey*). However, @hunter seems to disapprove of that idea. I'm not sure why. Comments?

Answer (score 1):

Explicit namespaces will do the trick.

You can merge your `Donkey` classes, if they are in fact the same structurally, to another project which the two namespaces can reference.

If you have control over how these disparate `Donkey` classes are conceived you can allow them each to share an interface `IDonkey` but that's more or less the same syntactical solution to merging.

Comment: I have no control over the conception of the *Donkey* instances at all. Would you, please, elaborate on the merging of the two classes? I just noticed that the classes **might** have different information in them. Do you mean designing a class *DonkeyBridge* that has two constructors, interpreting the internal natives to an internal data structure and exposing properties for *Donkey* this and *Donkey* that type? That's kind of brilliant idea! I should have thought of it myself. So I'm stealing it and claiming all the credit. :)   Or did you mean something else?

Comment: What you're suggesting is a third Donkey which is against the laws of nature.

Comment: If you did create a `DonkeyBridge` how would you use it? What you do really depends on how you're going to abuse this `Donkey`

Comment: I meant that I'd have a third class that can take as a input to the constructor any of pre-existing *Donkey* classes and produce a new instance of the *Donkey* class that I request. I'm getting the impression that you meant something else by merger class. Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: by merging I meant eliminating the other two classes and making a new class. from your comments I see that that is not possible.

Comment: Oh... What a anti-climax... I'll take that the donkey-to-donkey converter is back on the table. I feel like a donkey (the other way to say it, starting with an "a") now...