# use different namespaces in one class

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, namespaces

I have a winform application which works with AutoCAD software. It works fine with AutoCAD 2012 and lower versions of AutoCAD but now i want to enable my application to work with upper versions of this software.

So i need to use three different namespaces, two of them for AutoCAD 2004 up to 2012 and one of them for AutoCAD 2013 and upper.

Now i'm looking for the best way to use the classes of these three namespaces as far as possible in one module, with no need to define them twice.

**NOTE:** These namespaces has different names but they have same classes with same names.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any other way. You can make an aliases in using directives:

```
using MC=MyCompany.ERP;
using MB=MyCompany.Barcode;
...
public void Test()
{
  var a = MC.Utilities.Method();
  var b = MB.Utilities.Method();
}
```

It's the simplest way to manage them.
Source: [How to handle same class name in different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345037/how-to-handle-same-class-name-in-different-namespaces)

Comment: Thanks Vignesh Kumar for your immediate reply, Does not an interface help in this case?Or a parent class?