# System and UnityEngine are colliding with each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use DateTime.Now in Unity, but it won't work due to the Random class existing in both namespaces. Are there any alternatives to DateTime inUnity?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class coinspawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject coin;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            GameObject spawnedcoin = Instantiate(coin, SpawnCoin(), transform.rotation);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(DateTime.Now - date > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            GameObject spawnedcoin = Instantiate(coin, SpawnCoin(), transform.rotation);
        }
    }
    Vector3 SpawnCoin()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(-9f, 9f); //The Random-class exists in both System and UnityEngine
        float z = Random.Range(-9f, 9f);
        Vector3 spawnlocation = new Vector3(x, 0.2717659f, z);
        return spawnlocation;
    }
}
```

I found a solution, I was just too dumb to think about itin the first place.

Just use `using static System.DateTime;` and no other classes such as Random are used which could make problems!

Comment: Use the fully qualified name `UnityEngine.Random` or `System.Random`.  Or use a namespace alias as shown in [How to handle same class name in different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13345037).  In fact I think that question answers yours, agree?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle same class name in different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345037/how-to-handle-same-class-name-in-different-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Use the full type names like so:

```
var x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-9f, 9f);
var z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-9f, 9f);
```

Also, quick clean code tip, replace `0.2717659f` with a const value:

```
const float SPAWN_Y = 0.2717659f;
// Code
Vector3 spawnlocation = new Vector3(x, SPAWN_Y, z);
```